# Is ReplaySubject(1) the same as AsyncSubject()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently using this to perform notifications:

```
  /**
   * Create notifications that broacast
   * the entire set of entries.
   */
  protected notify = new ReplaySubject<E[]>(1);
```

IIUC I can switch out the `ReplaySubject<E[]>(1)` with `AsyncSubject<E[]>()`?

Would this be an apple to apple switch or might here be semantic differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they're very much not the same.

ReplaySubject(1) will always replay the latest emission no matter when the observer subscribes. It can emit any number of times.

AsyncSubject ignores all emissions until the observable completes, then emits the last emitted value. It can only ever emit once (at most) and when it does, it will also complete.

Comment: Right, a ReplaySubject(1) is more like a BehaviorSubject until completion, for the ReplaySubject(1) will emit the last value to subscribers *post-completion*, while  BehaviorSubject will not.

Comment: Just wanted to mention one thing though - the last part of this answer might be misleading i.e. "It can only ever emit once (at most) and when it does, it will also complete.". Calling `next()` on an `AsyncSubject` will not complete it. You'll have to `complete()` manually.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/packages/rxjs/src/internal/AsyncSubject.ts#L24