# Assigning an id to a generic Type where the id property name is configurable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic type `E`.  It is an Entity instance like `Customer`, `Product`, `Todo`, etc.  Is has two configurable fields `id` and `guid`, however they are not necessarily named that.  The names for those two properties are configurable.

Here's an example of an Entity:

```
class Todo {
    id: string;
    gid: string;
    title: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

In order to configure the property names a config class like this is used:

```
    /**
    * Store configuration.
    */
    export class StoreConfig {
    idKey?:string ='id';
    guidKey?:string ='gid';
    }
```

The StoreConfig is used to determine the names of the properties on instances of type `E` that generated IDs are assigned to.  So we have a method like this:

```
/**
* Post (Add a new) element to the store.
* @param e
*/
post(e: E) {  
    const guid: string = v1();
    e[this.config.guid] = guid;
    this.entries[guid] = e;
```

Typescript throws:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature 
>    (property) EStore.config: StoreConfig

Is there a way to fix this?  It's a little trick, because the `E` type has two properties wholes names are configurable ...?

Also the class essentially has two index signatures.  One for the `id` property (Also not yet named / it is configurable) and one for the `guid` property (Also not yet named / it is configurable) ...

If I do:

```
    (<any>e)[this.config.guidKey] = guid;
```

Typescript does not complain, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to declare this?

Comment: Can you post the full code? I don't see how your `E` generic is declared.

Comment: Why not mark an answer as accepted on your [old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335556/is-replaysubject1-the-same-as-asyncsubject) before asking a new one?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @IngoBürk - I usually mark it accepted right away, but there's a delay on SO, so occasionally I forget.

Comment: @Jacob I updated the question with a code example.  It's for this library that I'm currently in process of updating: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need type parameters for the names of the two properties.  (Well, since the properties have the same type `string`, you could use a single type parameter with a union type, but that's a hack IMO.)  Then you can use a mapped type to declare the actual properties.

```
interface StoreConfig<I extends string, G extends string> {
    idKey: I;
    guidKey: G;
}

type EntityBase<I extends string, G extends string> =
    // TODO: In TypeScript 3.1, change to the following for elegance:
    //{[P in I]: string} & {[P in G]: string}
    {[P in I | G]: string};

class Store<I extends string, G extends string, E extends EntityBase<I, G>> {
    constructor(private config: StoreConfig<I, G>) {}

    entries: {[guid: string]: E};

    post(e: E) {  
        const guid: string = v1();
        e[this.config.guidKey] = guid;
        this.entries[guid] = e;
    }
}

// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571 will make this nicer.
new Store<"id", "gid", Todo>({idKey: "id", guidKey: "gid"});
```